# Two RigidBodies - How Do I Make One Immobile?

Tags: unity-game-engine

In a 2D shooter, I have one RigidBody that is a rotating wall.  My player (ship) is another RigidBody.  Both have gravity of 0 and are non-kinematic.  I want the ship to not be able to move the wall, but to halt up against it.  Currently, the ship hits it and both are affected by the collision and start floating around.

Is the proper way to accomplish this to set the constrain Y and Z on the rotating wall so that it can't be moved by a collision with the ship?  When I do this, the rotating wall's rotation stops working so before I go further down that path I wanted to see if this is the canonical approach to making something with a rigidbody immobile (constraining X and Y).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the one you don't want to move kinematic

Answer (score 0):

I've been through this, I had a wall and a character with RigidBody.
I didn't want the wall to move in a collision with the character, to solve that, I just made the wall a LOOOTT heavier than the character, just make the "MASS" of the wall very high! The character will not be able to move it!  /o/

Hope that helps!